# async nature in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am newbie to node.js , i cant figure out how to solve this. As node.js is async nature i cant predict the result in a  structured manner...

My scenario is as follows:

```
aysnc.foreach(Object.keys(req.body), function(elem){
    if(elem !== aaaa){
        client.search(Query).then(function(Data){
            //----------> For every query is a callback, so after 
            // sending the result to front-end this callback is returning. 
            // I have to make this query executed and return result and 
            // after that only the next loop should start.

            //some logic here
            arr1;-------------->populating result for each query
       });
    } else {
     aysnc.foreach(Object.keys(req.body.xxxx), function(elem){
        client.search(Query).then(function(Data){
        //some logic here
        arr2;
        });
    });
```

});
Finally what i have to do is:

```
if(--Object.keys(req.body).length === 0){
intersect arr1 an arr2
}
```

I have to intersect arr1 and arr2. But before populating arr1 and arr2, the async nature completes the loop and arr1 and arr2 is empty.

I have to make everything sync. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code that is properly indented, has no syntax errors and fully reproduces your problem.

Comment: What is the async element? Async.foreach

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using async.js of caolan? link: https://github.com/caolan/async

try something like this.

```
var counter = 0;
var arr1 = [];
async.each(Object.keys(req.body), function(elem, callback) {
  //checks if counter, if equal callback to send the total
  if(counter == req.body.length) {        
    callback(null, arr1);
  } else {
    //do your query here
    // put your if else here
    counter++;
    if(elem == null) {
      //call callback for error
      callback('error elem is null', null)
    }
  }
}, function(err, total){
    if( err ) {
       res.send(400);
    } else {
       res.send(200);
      //you will see the the combined array here
      console.log(total);
      console.log('processed successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But console.log(total); is coming as undefined for me.